# Content Delivery Policy setup

Tags: security, cdn

I want to secure my website using a [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introducing_Content_Security_Policy). I'm came up with the following policy:

```
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src https://www.example.com https://static.example.com; script-src https://ajax.googleapis.com
```

I have two questions regrding the Content Security Policy I want to set.

1. I use Google's CDN only to get the jQuery library. Is it possible to make a policy that only allows certain scripts to load from a domain instead of the generic `script-src`?
2. Is my policy correct? E.g. having two domains for the `default-src` and a separate one for `script-src`. Will I still be able to server `script-src` files through my own domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q1: No. In the [W3C spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/content-security-policy/raw-file/tip/csp-specification.dev.html) it says that script-src specifies hosts as follows:

```
( [ scheme "://" ] host [ port ] )
```

so nothing after the host or port can be used.

For Q2: From my reading of the spec, yes, it's correct.

> If not specified explicitly in the policy, the directives listed above
>   will use the default sources.

So you have two domains as defaults for everything, and then you further refine script-src with a particular domain. However if you want to serve script-src files from your own domain then you'll need to add your domain after ajax.googleapis.com.